# Given a C++ library, can I find out what C++ standard was used to compile it

Tags: c++, linux

For example, I have the lib `libtensorflow_framework.so.2`. I want to compile another lib which can link to this (e.g. in case of TensorFlow, a custom op).

In my use case, it is necessary that I use the right C++ version (e.g. `-std=c++17` or whatever). This is because of Abseil, which requires it for binary compatibility (see [here](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/issues/211)).

I know that the lib was compiled with GCC, and I also know the GCC version.

Is it possible to find out just from this lib file what was the C++ version it was compiled with?

From the comments so far, it seems "no", at least in the general case, as it was demonstrated for a simple very minimal example. However, in my particular case, I know there there will be differences in the lib binary file, depending on the C++ standard.

(This question is not meant to be specific to this TensorFlow example but generic. However, if the answer is GCC or Linux specific, or even Abseil specific, that would be fine to me.)

Comment: what is "custom op"?

Comment: From my admittedly fascistic point of view, if you need to know, the library's interface is broken.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't exactly understand. You always need to know this for C++, right? At least libraries like the STL require this. And in the case of TF, Abseil requires it as well.

Comment: I really don't think so. There is nothing stopping you from linking against libraries compiled 20 years ago.

Comment: The C++ language standard level which you chose to compile with wouldn’t have any effect on the ABI.

Comment: Ok, maybe this is specific to Abseil then, which depends on the STL. For example: https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/issues/211

Comment: comments in the link seem to indicate you need to compile the library yourself an not depend on a pre-built binary

Comment: @NeilButterworth It is supported when you use the same compiler, same C++ standard and the same headers. Which is not difficult to get. If I only know the C++ standard. I already know the GCC version.

Comment: [No](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37fbbf23c6a883ab). (This space intentionally left blank)

Comment: @Albert second comment in link seems to say otherwise

Comment: It says "compiling both libraries at the same time, with the same compiler options". Except of "at the same time" (why should the time be relevant?), this is exactly what I want to do here.

Comment: @Albert the second comment in that link is telling you to compile abseil yourself rather than rely on a precompiled version. since you'd be compiling it yourself you can pick whatever standard you want (assuming it meets whatever requirements abseil has for building)

Comment: How did you compile the `libtensorflow_framework.so.2`?

Comment: @HotelCalifornia I don't want to recompile TF which comes with Abseil. Thus I must use the same standard as TF. So this is why I asked the question here.

Comment: @Eljay I did not compile it, but that should not be relevant. It was compiled with GCC, with some C++ standard, and this question here is about finding it out, just based on the binary.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Ah thanks for this, so I guess in general the answer is no. But your specific example is very minimal, and maybe once some more actual C++ features are used, then you can tell from the binary?

Comment: @Albert You can of course look through the symbols used in the library and look in them for types that wouldn't be present in certain standard versions, but that's going to be a lot of work to do with some rigor and no guarantee that it will tell you anything, in particular if the library is stripped. Individual translation units used in the library may also be compiled with different C++ revision flags, which you really can't tell apart.

Comment: Sure if an object uses a C++17 function and it happens not to be inlined, you can tell that by the presence of the symbol. But there is no guarantee.

Comment: "I know that the lib was compiled with GCC, and I also know the GCC version." do you know what all the flags passed to that GCC version were? Precompiled C++ libraries are, to a very good approximation, not distributable

Comment: @Caleth Yes, I know all other relevant flags. TensorFlow provides this information via an API. I just don't know the C++ standard, which is required though for this case.

Comment: Actually, current TF master also provide the information on the C++ standard via an API. But no stable release does yet.